# Please help me figure this out How many options are their?

Tags: word-problem

Kylie is having a BBQ for the senior class of 2020!

She will be serving hamburgers, hotdogs,
 and brats. There will be coleslaw, potato salad, fruit, and pasta salad for sides. She has cake, cookies, and pie for dessert. They can choose pop or water to drink. Assuming everyone has one main dish, side, dessert, and drink, how many different meal combinations are there for Kylie's guests?

Answer (score 0):

There will be $3×4×3×2=72$ different combinations.